# "So as" + adverb + subject?

Tags: meaning-in-context, comparison, inversion

Is this a inversion?

> "**So as** softly she wanders I'll desperately follow her footsteps
>   and I'll chase after shadows that offer a trace of her sight
>   Ah, they promise eternally that she lays hidden within them
>   but I find they've decieved me and sadly I bid them goodbye"

Could that be rewritten like:
While she wanders, I'll desperately follow her footsteps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a rearrangement (not an inversion), but *so as* is not the subject.

*So* is an adverb = 'thus' or 'consequently'

*As* is what traditional grammar called a subordinating conjunction; *CGEL* calls it a preposition. It is equivalent here to *when* or *while*.

The actual clause is "Softly she wanders" which represents "She wanders softly", with the adverb moved to the front.

So the whole thing may be paraphrased pretty much as you suggest:

> Consequently: while she wanders softly . . .

But of course that will wreck the meter!

Comment: Hehe funny, always perfect answers :)

Comment: So this has no comparison value?  
It is just describing the situation: while she is walking soflty, he is   chasing her.  
If I change the order for this, make any sense?  
So softly she wanders as I'll desperately  follow her footsteps.  
( here I'm trying to pass the idea of the same intensity of action, but in   opposed situations)

Comment: "so" is not connected to "as".  This is not an instance of idiomatic "so as" .Think of it as having a comma between them. "so" is like an interjection; "as she walks" means "while she walks".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Ah, thank you: I missed this source of confusion.